# Why i am getting response like this form linkedin? 410 Error

Tags: php, sdk, linkedin-api

When i am trying to login in linkedin via php sdk, I am getting this kind of response.

> it was not possible to access the API call: it was returned an unexpected > > response status 410 Response: { "errorCode": 0, "message": "This resource is > no longer available under v1 APIs", "requestId": "SGLV7JGIW9", "status": >410, "timestamp": 1556696042967 }

I need to login into own system via linkedin. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code that you've tried, so people can help you better. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth_token=81--7a2e3182-577c-4acd-ba14-12bbcbe84948&oauth_verifier=28551 

I am hitting this kind of url in browser still i not getting any kind of response form linekdin server still it shows me blank data.

Comment: Make sure to *edit* your question and add the stuff you mentioned. That way, people don't need to look into comments to understand your problem and can help to solve it more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

From you error message:

> This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs

... which implies you are using the `v1` API of linkedin

Mircrosoft/linkedin has long communicated, at least on its [blog](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) and [API migration FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq) that `v1` API would be deprecated **today** (1st of May 2019) and that all developers were required to migrate their app to `v2`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the v2 oAuth platform for Linkedin as v1 is no longer available (We are doing the same) the Microsfot documentation isn't the best however for the API

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed code with v2 oauth still i am facing data blank issue. Do you have any suggestions?